# Stuck on the Proof on Fisher's Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, determinant, combinatorial-designs

I'm confused about the proof that for a balanced design with parameters $(v, b, r, k, \lambda)$, if $v \gt k$, then $b \ge v$.

If you let $M$ be the incidence matrix of the design such that $M_{ij}$ is $1$ if the point $i$ is in the block $j$, and $0$ otherwise, then M is a $(v \times b)$ matrix. Now, let $B = MM^t$. Then

$det(B)=$ $$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    r & \lambda & \lambda & ... & \lambda \\
    \lambda & r & \lambda & ... & \lambda \\
    \lambda & \lambda & r & ... & \lambda \\
   ... & ... & ... & ... & ...   \\
    \lambda & \lambda & \lambda & ... & r \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

$=$ $$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    r & \lambda & \lambda & ... & \lambda \\
    \lambda - r & r - \lambda & 0 & ... & 0 \\
    \lambda - r & 0 & r - \lambda & ... & 0 \\
   ... & ... & ... & ... & ...   \\
    \lambda - r & 0 & 0 & ... & r - \lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
$=$
$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    r + (v-1)\lambda& \lambda & \lambda & ... & \lambda \\
    0 & r - \lambda & 0 & ... & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & r - \lambda & ... & 0 \\
   ... & ... & ... & ... & ...   \\
    0& 0 & 0 & ... & r - \lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

However, I'm confused about how $$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    r & \lambda & \lambda & ... & \lambda \\
    \lambda - r & r - \lambda & 0 & ... & 0 \\
    \lambda - r & 0 & r - \lambda & ... & 0 \\
   ... & ... & ... & ... & ...   \\
    \lambda - r & 0 & 0 & ... & r - \lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
 got to
$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    r + (v-1)\lambda& \lambda & \lambda & ... & \lambda \\
    0 & r - \lambda & 0 & ... & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & r - \lambda & ... & 0 \\
   ... & ... & ... & ... & ...   \\
    0& 0 & 0 & ... & r - \lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$.

I understand that the determinants of two matrices A and B are equal if B was obtained from A by adding a constant times a row onto another row of A. I also get all the other rules of determinants when it comes to elementary row operations, but I don't understand how the elementary row operations *themselves* produced that final matrix I gave above.

Can anyone please explain this to me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Better to forget about the determinant and focus on eigenvalues. The all-one matrix $J$ has eigenvalues $0$ and $v$, so your matrix $\lambda J+(r-\lambda)I$ has eigenvalues $r-\lambda$ and $r-\lambda+v\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use column operations too!

Just add each of columns $2$, $3,\ldots,v$ to column $1$.

Comment: Thanks for that! It explains everything.